# JSON Encode showing unexpected shashes

Tags: php, json

When I encode data it adds unexpected slash.

Here is data

```
 ""\"\\\"[{\\\\\\\"PropertyId\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"544068\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanId\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2175341\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"50 Regent 1AP\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Beds\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Baths\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1.00\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumSQFT\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"667\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumSQFT\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"667\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumRent\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2475\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumRent\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2475\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumDeposit\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumDeposit\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"AvailableUnitsCount\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"AvailabilityURL\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanImageURL\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"http:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/cdn.rentcafe.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/dmslivecafe\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/3\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/544068\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/50Reg1AP.jpg\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanImageName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"50Reg1AP.jpg\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"PropertyShowsSpecials\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanHasSpecials\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"UnitTypeMapping\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0050r1ap\\\\\\\"}]\\\"\"""
```

Comment: "When I encode data" — When you encode what data? Why don't you expect those slashes? What do you expect? Provide a real [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` prevents the escaping of `/` characters. There are no `/` characters in the data in the question, so that will have no effect at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
function removeslashes($string)
{
    $string=implode("",explode("\\",$string));
    return stripslashes(trim($string));
}

/* Example */

$text="""\"\\\"[{\\\\\\\"PropertyId\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"544068\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanId\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2175341\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"50 Regent 1AP\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Beds\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Baths\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1.00\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumSQFT\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"667\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumSQFT\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"667\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumRent\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2475\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumRent\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2475\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MinimumDeposit\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"MaximumDeposit\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"AvailableUnitsCount\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"AvailabilityURL\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanImageURL\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"http:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/cdn.rentcafe.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/dmslivecafe\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/3\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/544068\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/50Reg1AP.jpg\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanImageName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"50Reg1AP.jpg\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"PropertyShowsSpecials\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"FloorplanHasSpecials\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"UnitTypeMapping\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0050r1ap\\\\\\\"}]\\\"\"""";
echo removeslashes($text);
?>
```